# How to build the MMSB model with pymc3?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3, inference

[Here is the model I want to describe in pymc3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ReSk.jpg).
I wrote the following codes, but they do not work.

```
with pm.Model() as model:   
    bernoulli_parameters = np.empty([N, N], dtype=object)
    for n in range(N):  
        for m in range(N):
            if (z[n,m]==z[n,m]):
                bernoulli_parameters[n,m] = myBeta[z[n,m]]
            else:
                bernoulli_parameters[n,m] = epsilon
    bernoulli_parameters_vector=bernoulli_parameters.reshape(1,N*N)    
    D = pm.Bernoulli('D',                                 
            p=bernoulli_parameters_vector, observed=Topology_Data_Vector)
```

Comment: Please add the sample input and output: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: As both z[n,m] and z[m,n] are hidden variables, I found I can not compare z[n,m] with z[m,n]. (z[n,m] == z[m,n] is always false).

Comment: Besides, I can not use hidden variable z[m,n] as the index of myBeta, namely myBeta[z[m,n]] also does not work.

Comment: The question is same as https://discourse.pymc.io/t/how-to-build-the-mmsb-model-with-pymc3/896